# Why is this simple UDP socket scanner failing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, udp, port

I have set up a simple UDP port scanner. It goes through all the ports in a specified range, sends some text, and checks if it receives a response. I am currently testing it on a UDP port that I know is open, and will send a text message back when it receives input, but it isn't working so for some reason the udpsock.recvfrom(1024) line isn't doing what it should.

```
for port in (start, end):
        try:
            udpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            udpsock.bind(('', 0))
            udpsock.settimeout(2)
            udpsock.sendto(b'PINGxyz123', (target, port))
            while True:
                data = udpsock.recvfrom(1024)
                if len(data) > 0:
                    udp_ports_found += 1
                    print(data)
                    print("UDP Port {}:    Open".format(port))
                    break
                    if report == 'y': # If the user requested a report of the scanner's findings
                        with open("udpfindings.txt", "w+") as f2: # Create a file which all findings will be written to; a report for all intents and purposes
                            file2 = f2.read()
                            f2.write("UDP Port {}:    Open".format(port))                        
            udpsock.close()

        except KeyboardInterrupt: # If Ctrl+C is pressed
            print("Scan aborted.")
            sys.exit() # Crash the program

        except socket.timeout:
            pass
```

Any ideas would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You never set the local port of the socket, so how can it receive anything?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said before that this is just a section of the code. All variables were declared earlier on.

Comment: That has nothing to do with my question. You never bound `udpsock` to a local port that it listens for responses on.

Comment: So do I need to bind the socket to 127.0.0.1 first?

Comment: You need to bind the socket to a PORT.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: `udpsock.bind(('', 9999))` will bind it to port 9999.

Comment: Can it be any port?

Comment: Unprivileged code is restricted from using ports lower than 1024. And it shouldn't be a port that's in use by other applications.

Comment: I think you can use port 0 and it will automatically select an unused port.

Comment: I have updated the question with some new code. Does this look better?

Comment: Does it work or not?

Comment: It doesn't work.